# To extend a warm and welcoming invitation to someone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single verb or short verb phrase in English language that means **"to extend a warm and welcoming invitation to someone"**?

I was recently asked this question but I am not a native speaker, so I was not sure.

Comment: @choster I don't think the question is asking for single-word ways to extend a welcome, but rather a single word that means the act of extending such a welcome. It seems much like any other single-word request question to me.

Comment: Sorry, said "extend a welcome" but meant "invitation".

Comment: In shortening the phrase you remove much of the warmth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase that comes to my mind would be ***cordially invite***:

> Something that is done *cordially* has warmth and friendliness to it, like a host who greets people cordially at a party. In fact, formal party invitations sometimes use the phrase *"you are cordially invited,"* which means you are happily encouraged to attend.
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cordially)</sub>